# Self Signed SSL For Development Server Broken Everything Wordpress - Apache

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ssl

It turns out that the latest Facebook SDK for js login needs to be run from https. So I created a self-signed certificate for my development machine and set up apache to see it.

Everything is fine when I access a simple file like https://local.domain/phpfile.php but Wordpress just won't load! It says it can't load the main site, it can't load wp-admin/ - but all this works ok HTTP, nothing has changed except the virtual host listening on port 443 instead of 80 (and said about that a static PHP file loads fine):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/localdevsite.com/_www
ServerName localdevsite.com
ServerAlias www.localdevsite.com
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

Could do with some help here, I have no idea why it just wouldn't load, all that I have done is add a self-signed SSL and changed the port in the virtual host and as I say it all works perfectly fine without the SSL on port 80.

So basically can't access a Wordpress install on https://localdevsite.com but can on http://localdevsite.com and can access https://localdevsite.com/singlephpfile.php

Comment: Did u change wp address to include https?

Comment: Yes , the problem being that the home page won’t even load. If I comment out wp config as to install fresh it shows : the requested url /wp-admin/setup-config.php was not found. It seems it’s not getting access to any folders but can access files in the doc root. Don’t get it , it works fine on http

Comment: Access it with http and update the sites address to use httpS then make your Apache changes. You may also edit the site URL directly in the database.

Comment: Any caching plugin (that might have some inpact). Did you check phpmyadmin wp-options table?

Comment: I’ve done all the db changes, I develop for WordPress all the time but this doesn’t seem like it’s acrually directly related to wordpess. Can’t access any file inside a folder on https, only files in the doc root

Comment: Even with htaccess removed and a blank upload of wordpess doesn’t work it can’t access the admin folder

Comment: Figured it out, the ssl.conf wasn't done right!